# Check if request was sent by Ajax or not

Tags: ajax, magento

I am overriding a magento controller, before processing, is there a way to know if the request was sent by Ajax or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('ajax')){
    //Ajax related code
} else {
    //Non ajax
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that's wrong. Even though some admin controllers of Magento _do_ submit an `ajax` param with their forms (and sometimes an `isAjax` param), there also are many Magento controllers (e.g. checkout) that do _not_ do this. And even if so, an existing param `ajax` does *not* tell anything about whether the request was sent using Ajax. Having a simple `<input name="ajax" value="1" />` in any form would match your `if` condition on submission, too. Even if such form is submitted by POST. Checking for `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` headers tells you s/t more reliable.

Comment: Actually, this is the right way, some Magento widgets use IFrames, and append the ajax parameter, so checking for HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH is useless..

Comment: I think that depends on how you define "Ajax". To me, it's only XmlHttpRequests. To you, it's only an `ajax` params. To Magento it seems to be both^^ I updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 37):

Magento uses the class `Zend_Controller_Request_Http` for its requests.

You can use

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    // is Ajax request
}
```

to detect Ajax requests this way.

At least

- Prototype
- Scriptaculous
- jQuery
- YUI
- MochiKit

send the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header, according to the [ZF docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.request.html#zend.controller.request.http.ajax).

Note though, "Ajax requests" means requests sent using **XmlHttpRequest** (and *not* using techniques like hidden `<iframe>`s, or Flash uploaders, or the like) to me.

Since this is subjective and your perception may differ: Magento itself seems to define "Ajax" in some more extended way than I do. Have a look at `Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http::isAjax()`:

```
public function isAjax()
{
    if ($this->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return true;
    }
    if ($this->getParam('ajax') || $this->getParam('isAjax')) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Depending on your personal perception of "Ajax", this may (or may not) better fit your needs.

Comment: For those who need to know this information elsewhere than a controller (such as an observer), you can use `Mage::app()->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()`

Answer (score 11):

If Im not mistaken, magento is written using Zend Framework, therefor by using the Request object you can do

```
if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()){
    // ajax
} else {
    // not ajax
}
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.request.html#zend.controller.request.http.ajax

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 3):

Magento internally uses a mix of of both.

Zend Framework's isXmlHttpRequest() checks header.

```
public function isXmlHttpRequest(){
  return ($this->getHeader('X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest');
}
```

In some cases magento uses isXmlHttpRequest() like in Mage_ImportExport_Adminhtml_ExportController::getFilterAction()

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest() && $data) {
  //code
}
```

In other cases it checks get parameter like in Mage_Catalog_Product_CompareController::removeAction()

```
if (!$this->getRequest()->getParam('isAjax', false)) {
  $this->_redirectReferer();
}
```

Request Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http::isAjax() checks for both

```
public function isAjax()

{
    if ($this->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return true;
    }
    if ($this->getParam('ajax') || $this->getParam('isAjax')) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I would suggest to use Request object isAjax as it checks for Both.

Answer (score 1):

The best mehtod is :

```
if (!$this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use pure PHP and never care:

```
   public function isAjax()
   {
      return (boolean)((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) && ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest'));
   }
```

Comment: I will never understand those people using different frameworks like ZFW, Magentoo, etc for this purposes, U should always remember different syntax for that - WHY?! - Just use one line of code and it will be run (faster, safer) everywhere =)

Comment: Redundancy is rather FrameWork parts ) Wrappers, lazy loding objects, multiple inheritance all this for just one call `$this->getRequest()->getParam('ajax')` - just imagine how many code are executing every time users run different parts of Your app - there is a logic ot determine whether it is ajax or something else, instance of getRequest() (Requests object) and so on... just for this functionality `return (boolean)((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) && ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest'));`

Comment: Re "redundance": the OP uses a Magento controller, which means there already _is_ a request object containing a proper method, so defining a new method doing the same as the existing one will create redundancy. Re "faster": calling your `isAjax()` method is slower than using the condition directly, hence performance-wise not the optimum, too. However, no matter whether using the built-in Magento/ZF method, your method, or the condition directly, the performance difference will not be significant at all (some nanoseconds, probably). Re "safer": I fail to see how your method should me more safe.